# The Tkinter input is not inserting into database (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

When I click Add on tkinter it doesn't add anything in database
I don't know sqlite3 alot.

My Database File:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import *
conn = sqlite3.connect("connects.db")
print("Opened database successfully")
cursor = conn.cursor()

def createTable():
    conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contactlist
             (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
             NAME         TEXT    NOT NULL,
             PHONE        INT     NOT NULL);''')

    print ("Table created successfully")


cursor.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Python File:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
from DatabaseFile import *
import sqlite3

def selection () :
    print ("At %s of %d" % (select.curselection(), len(contactlist)))
    return int(select.curselection()[0])

def addContact() :
    conn = sqlite3.connect('connects.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    entry = (nameVar.get(), phoneVar.get())
    try:
        def insertContact(entry):
            conn.execute('INSERT INTO contactlist (NAME, PHONE) VALUES (?,?)', (entry))
            conn.commit()
            print('record inserted in data')
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning("Field cannot be blank","Please enter a value in both the fields.")
    else:
        setList()


def updateContact() :
    contactlist[selection()]=[nameVar.get(), phoneVar.get()]
    setList ()

def deleteContact() :
    del contactlist[selection()]
    setList ()

def loadContact  () :
    name, phone = contactlist[selection()]
    nameVar.set(name)
    phoneVar.set(phone)

def saveContact  () :
    fobj = open("contacts.py", "w")
    fobj.write("contactlist = [")
    for items in contactlist:
        fobj.write(str(items))
        fobj.write(",")
        fobj.write("\n")
    fobj.write("]")

def exitContact  () :
    app_title = "Contacts"
    if (messagebox.askokcancel(title = app_title, \
        message = "Do you want to exit, OK or Cancel") == 1) :
        os._exit(1)

def buildFrame () :
    global nameVar, phoneVar, select
    root = Tk()
    root.title('My Contact List')

    frame1 = Frame(root)
    frame1.pack()

    Label(frame1, text="Name:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    nameVar = StringVar()
    name = Entry(frame1, textvariable=nameVar)
    name.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

    Label(frame1, text="Phone:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    phoneVar= StringVar()
    phone= Entry(frame1, textvariable=phoneVar)
    phone.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

    frame1 = Frame(root)       # add a row of buttons
    frame1.pack()
    btn1 = Button(frame1,text=" Add  ",command=addContact)
    btn2 = Button(frame1,text="Update",command=updateContact)
    btn3 = Button(frame1,text="Delete",command=deleteContact)
    btn4 = Button(frame1,text=" Load ",command=loadContact)
    btn5 = Button(frame1,text=" save ",command=saveContact)
    btn6 = Button(frame1,text=" exit ",command=exitContact)
    btn1.pack(side=LEFT); btn2.pack(side=LEFT)
    btn3.pack(side=LEFT); btn4.pack(side=LEFT)
    btn5.pack(side=LEFT); btn6.pack(side=RIGHT)

    frame1 = Frame(root)       # allow for selection of names
    frame1.pack()
    scroll = Scrollbar(frame1, orient=VERTICAL)
    select = Listbox(frame1, yscrollcommand=scroll.set, height=7)
    scroll.config (command=select.yview)
    scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    select.pack(side=LEFT,  fill=BOTH)
    return root

def setList() :
    global contacts
    contacts = readContacts()
    # sort the list
    contacts.sort(key = lambda x : x[1])
    # delete all elements from the select element
    select.delete(0, END)
    # insert each name from the list to the end of the              # select
        # element
    for id, name, phone in contacts :
        select.insert(END, name)

def readContacts():
    contactlistss = []
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM contactlist")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        contactlistss = row
    return contactlistss



# the main program
# initialize the application by building the GUI elements
root = buildFrame()
# initialize the database
createTable()
# set the contents of the list initially
setList()
to keep the program from exiting
root.mainloop()
# end of program
```

when clicking the add button on tkinter its giving me blank ouput that means its not inserting anything in database

Comment: Please try to make a **minimal** code example. This will help us and maybe you find the solution by yourself. You can also have a look at [How to debug a program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Only need help on that addContact()  function its not entering any inputs into database

Comment: do you get error message ? You should always use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` to see what exception you get - this way you can see what can be the problem.

Comment: you have problem because you define function `def insertContact(entry):` but you never run it. I don't know why you define this function - you should put code directly in `try/except`

Answer (score 0):

Inside `try/except` you define `def insertContact(entry):` but you never execute this function. But you could put code directly in `try/excet`

```
try:
    conn.execute('INSERT INTO contactlist (NAME, PHONE) VALUES (?,?)', (entry))
    conn.commit()
    print('record inserted in data')
except Exceptiona as ex:
    print('Ex:', ex)
    messagebox.showwarning("Field cannot be blank","Please enter a value in both the fields.")
else:
    setList()
```

---

**BTW:** I checked all code and there are my changes. Not all works yet - ie. `Update` has problem.

I moved all queries to `DatabaseFile.py` and I open database only once and not close it till end of program.

I use `lower_case_names` for functions and variables. See: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

I removed `import *` - see also [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

DatabaseFile.py

```
import sqlite3


conn = None # default value at start 


def open():
    global conn

    conn = sqlite3.connect("connects.db")
    print("Opened database successfully")


def close():
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()


def create_table():
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contactlist
        (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
         NAME         TEXT    NOT NULL,
         PHONE        INT     NOT NULL);''')

    conn.commit()

    print("Table created successfully")


def read_contacts():
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM contactlist ORDER BY id")

    return cursor.fetchall()


def add_contact(name, phone):
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO contactlist (NAME, PHONE) VALUES (?,?)', (name, phone))

    conn.commit()

    print('record inserted in data')
```

---

main.py

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import DatabaseFile as db

def selection():
    print("At %s of %d" % (select.curselection(), len(contacts)))
    return int(select.curselection()[0])

def add_contact():
    try:
        db.add_contact(name_var.get(), phone_var.get())
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Ex:', ex)
        messagebox.showwarning("Field cannot be blank", "Please enter a value in both the fields.")
    else:
        set_list()

def update_contact():
    contacts[selection()] = [name_var.get(), phone_var.get()]
    set_list()

def delete_contact():
    del contacts[selection()]
    setList()

def load_contact():
    _, name, phone = contacts[selection()]
    name_var.set(name)
    phone_var.set(phone)

def save_contact():
    fobj = open("contacts.py", "w")
    fobj.write("contactlist = [")
    for items in contacts:
        fobj.write(str(items))
        fobj.write(",")
        fobj.write("\n")
    fobj.write("]")

def exit_contact():
    result = messagebox.askokcancel(title="Contacts", message="Do you want to exit, OK or Cancel")
    if result == 1:
        exit(1)

def build_frame():
    global name_var
    global phone_var
    global select

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('My Contact List')

    # ---

    frame_form = tk.Frame(root)
    frame_form.pack()

    tk.Label(frame_form, text="Name:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')

    name_var = tk.StringVar()
    name = tk.Entry(frame_form, textvariable=name_var)
    name.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')

    tk.Label(frame_form, text="Phone:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')

    phone_var = tk.StringVar()
    phone = tk.Entry(frame_form, textvariable=phone_var)
    phone.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')

    # ---

    frame_buttons = tk.Frame(root)
    frame_buttons.pack()

    btn1 = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text=" Add  ", command=add_contact)
    btn2 = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text="Update", command=update_contact)
    btn3 = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text="Delete", command=delete_contact)
    btn4 = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text=" Load ", command=load_contact)
    btn5 = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text=" Save ", command=save_contact)
    btn6 = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text=" Exit ", command=exit_contact)
    btn1.pack(side='left') 
    btn2.pack(side='left')
    btn3.pack(side='left') 
    btn4.pack(side='left')
    btn5.pack(side='left')
    btn6.pack(side='right')

    # ---

    frame_list = tk.Frame(root)
    frame_list.pack()

    scroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame_list, orient='vertical')
    select = tk.Listbox(frame_list, yscrollcommand=scroll.set, height=7)
    scroll.config(command=select.yview)
    scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    select.pack(side='left', fill='both')

    return root

def set_list() :
    global contacts

    contacts = db.read_contacts()

    select.delete(0, 'end')

    #for item in contacts:
    #    select.insert('end', item)

    select.insert('end', *contacts) # need star *  to insert all items at once

# --- main ---

contacts = [] # default value at start

# ---

db.open() # open once before program
db.create_table()

root = build_frame()

set_list()

root.mainloop()

db.close() # close after closing program
```

Comment: Its still giving me error 
Opened database successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TKcontacts.py", line 119, in <module>
    createTable()
  File "C:\\DatabaseFile.py", line 11, in createTable
    PHONE        INT     NOT NULL);''')
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.

Comment: now you have different problem and you should create new question with new description and full error message.

Comment: your problem is that inside `DatabaseFile.py` you open connection and you also close it outside functions so they are executed when you import this. So you close connection when you import this file adn later `createTable()` has no connection to database. You should open and close database inside `createTable()`

Comment: It still doesn;t work after opening the connection and closing inside the function giving the same error

Comment: did you remove other `conn.close()` from `DatabaseFile.py` ?

Comment: better create new question. You will have more place to show error message and describe problem. And we will have place for answers for new problem. On one page should be only one problem describe and resolved.

Comment: I'm new to sqlite3 didn't know about the closing and opening of connection

Comment: Also have problem understanding conn.commit()

Comment: `commit()` is used to confirm that you want to make changes in database. You can use 'ROLLBACK" to reject changes. You can also make few `execute` with one  `commit` at the end and it will send all changes to databases in one request. SO it should need less time for this.

Comment: Meanwhile I checked all code and I made few changes which I put in answer but without description.